# Parsing Json (list within dictionaries) in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to get sum of count
Below is my json:

```
json_data={
"note":abbcccc,
"comments":
    [{"count":100,"name"=leven},{"count":120,"name"=sam}]
}
```

How do I get the sum of all counts (100+120)

I can get indivdual like this:

```
data=json.loads(json_data)
count=data["comments"][0]["count"]
```

But stuck on "How to loop though it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through it like any list:

```
count = 0
for c in data['comments']:
  count += c['count']
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#sum):

```
count = sum(c["count"] for c in data["comments"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through each of the items in the `comments` list. Then pick `"count"` from each dict in that list. And add up.

```
data=json.loads(json_data)
total = 0
for each_counts in data["comments"]
    total += each_counts["count"]
```

This can be shortened to:

```
total = sum(each_count["count"] for each_count in data["comments"]
```